# Rails 3 - Calculated column

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to create a calculated field that multiply column1 and column2 on rails 3.

Like this :

```
totalpoint = column1 * column2
```

Where is I have to place the code? in the model? How do I write it?

How do I call it from my view?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think this is better placed on the model

```
attr_reader :totalpoint

def totalpoint
  column1 * column2
end
```

Give some instance `@m` of your model, it can be accessed anywhere (in an action, in the view, etc..) as

```
@m.totalpoint
```

You can access this from *within* the model simply with

```
@totalpoint
```

Answer (score 1):

In your controller create put the calculation in a instance variable (starts with `@`) in the action that is being called, eg index:

```
def index
  @totalpoint = column1 * column2
end
```

In your view (index.html.erb) you can use the instance variable:

```
<div>
  Total point = <%= @totalpoint %>
</div>
```

If you need to do this for multiple rows, you can use an array and use it in your view.